# Mysql raising intermittent "system error: 32" errors on connect

Tags: mysql

I'm running mysql 5.6.12 on OSX 10.8 and getting an error like this one constantly:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'sending authentication information', system error: 32
```

Once it starts, the error occurs no matter how I try to connect to mysql (console, my Ruby app, etc). Restarting the server is the only thing I've found that fixes it, and then it happens again within an hour, sometimes much more quickly.

I originally had a homebrew install, and it was having this problem. I then deleted that and installed with the official mysql .dmg package and a fresh database. That helped for a while, but now the problem has started again.

Comment: Have you checked MySQL's logs?

Comment: We are seeing this problem as well and were unable to get anything from our logs.

Comment: This doesn't look like the error in the log on the server.  There should be at least something.

Comment: It looks like this is related to partitioning. I'm partitioning a bunch of tables with a large number of partitions, and after I do so I start getting this error again. I suspect that I'm running out of file descriptors but not exactly sure how to evaluate the problem.